# How to prevent dark mode for emailer HTML if user using dark mode in mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually I have a emailer html now this is working fine but when user opening this emailer in mobile with dark mode then text automatically change to white color now I want to stop it because background should be always white even while user using in dark mode so how to prevent this there is any way to stop it?

What I tried:-

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind+Vadodara:400,500,600,700&amp;display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="font-family: 'Hind Vadodara', sans-serif; font-size: 16px !important; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; color: #000;">
    <table style="margin:auto;border-spacing: 0px; table-layout: fixed; max-width: 600px;">
        <tbody>
            
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                    <div style="padding:0px 20px; text-align: center; padding:0px 120px;">
                       <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase; color: #0c3668; text-align: center;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">  This is emailer heading</h2>
                       <p>
                       This is emailer content. This is emailer content. This is emailer content. This is emailer content. This is emailer content. This is emailer content. This is emailer content. This is emailer content.                  
                       </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

               

                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```